# How to append an argument to a container command?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) application built using `Dockerfile` that defines:

```
CMD node dist/bin/index.js
```

I'd like to "append" a parameter to the command as it is defined in Dockerfile, i.e. I want to execute the program as `node dist/bin/index.js foo`.

In [docker](/questions/tagged/docker) land I am able to achieve this via:

```
docker build --tag test .
docker run test foo
```

In [[image]kubernetes](/questions/tagged/kubernetes) I cannot use `command` because that will override the `ENTRYPOINT`. I cannot use `args` because that will override the `cmd` defined in the `Dockerfile`. It appears that my only option is:

```
cmd: ["node", "dist/bin/index.js", "foo"]
```

Is there a way to append an argument to a container command without redefining the entire Docker `CMD` definition?

Answer (score 1):

No way to append. You can either set the `command:` or `args:` on container.spec. You can learn more about how to override CMD/ENTRYPOINT here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/container-command-args/

Answer (score 0):

I don't there is a way to achieve what you want, except for setting the `cmd`, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I misunderstood your question, but if you just want to pass a parameter to the POD you can run your command inside the entrypoint script and use an environment variable that you pass to the container for that command. This should work in any Pod spec (as part of the deployment description for example).

Example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
```

For more see this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/define-environment-variable-container/).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve the same effect using an optional param in your Dockerfile:

```
ENV YOUR_OPTIONAL_PARAM
CMD node dist/bin/index.js $YOUR_OPTIONAL_PARAM
```