# Run Prometheus with docker failed when --enable-feature=promql-at-modifier

Tags: docker, prometheus

On Windows
I successfully run Prometheus from a docker image like this.

```
docker run -p 9090:9090 \
-v D:/WORK/MyProject/grafana:/etc/prometheus \
prom/prometheus
```

The `D:/WORK/MyProject/grafana` contains `prometheus.yml`  file with all configs I need.

Now I need to enable @ operator usage so I added `promql-at-modifier` tried to run

```
docker run -p 9090:9090 \
-v D:/WORK/MyProject/grafana:/etc/prometheus \
prom/prometheus --enable-feature=promql-at-modifier
```

I got the following:

```
level=info ts=2021-07-30T14:56:29.139Z caller=main.go:143 msg="Experimental promql-at-modifier enabled"
level=error ts=2021-07-30T14:56:29.139Z caller=main.go:356 msg="Error loading config (--config.file=prometheus.yml)" err="open prometheus.yml: no such file or directory"
```

Tried to google. There are suggestions to mount file

```
docker run -p 9090:9090 \
-v /path/to/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
prom/prometheus
```

(from https://www.promlts.com/resources/wheres-my-prometheus-yml)
But no luck.

Tried to specify config file option but again no luck.

Could you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try adding:

```
--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

i.e.

```sh
docker run --publish=9090:9090 \
--volume=D:/WORK/MyProject/grafana:/etc/prometheus \
prom/prometheus \
  --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
  --enable-feature=promql-at-modifier
```

> **Explanation**: Once you add flags (e.g. `--enable-feature`), other flags take default values. The default value for `--config.file` is `prometheus.yml` which is not what you want (you want `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`) and so you must explicitly reference it.

Answer (score 4):

I am a fan of docker, but it does have a few points of friction, and you found one of them.

https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/Dockerfile#L25 is where the upstream prometheus defines `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/prometheus" ]
CMD        [ "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml", \
             "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus", \
             "--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries", \
             "--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles" ]
```

The problem is, any arguments provided to the `docker run` command will *replace* the default `CMD`.    So in order to *append* arguments to the default `CMD`, you sadly need to copy the upstream CMD and then add your argument to the list.

Sadly, docker does not (currently!) support any way to "append" something to an upstream's CMD.  [How to append an argument to a container command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396569/how-to-append-an-argument-to-a-container-command) gives one idea for using an environment variable to do it.

In the general case where I want to provide default arguments *and* allow the invocation to provide additional arguments, I usually follow this pattern:

- Make the entrypoint launch a shell script
- `exec` the real entrypoint at the end of the shell script.  `exec`  *replaces* the shell with the real entrypoint, so that `exec` is important so signals are passed to the entrypoint and not the wrapper shell script.
- At the end of the arguments to `exec` within the script, add `"$@"`, which expands to the arguments of the shell script, quoted appropriately (yes, shell is quite esoteric!  you'd think it would quote *all* the arguments together, but instead it quotes *each* of the arguments because that token is magical)

In this way, the "default" commands are within the shell script and thus don't need to be included with `CMD`.  The downside to this method is that the shell script provided arguments are more difficult to remove if you wanted to.

Here's an example:

https://github.com/farrellit/stackoverflow/tree/main/68593213

The dockerfile includes a default CMD:

```
FROM alpine
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["7"]
```

the `entrypoint.sh` includes a set of "automatic" arguments to which is appended CMD, either default or overridden.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec echo 1 2 3 "$@"
```

The `Makefile` demonstrates to two invocations:

```
    docker run --rm stackoverflow-68593213
    docker run --rm stackoverflow-68593213 4 5 6
```

```
docker run --rm stackoverflow-68593213
1 2 3 7
docker run --rm stackoverflow-68593213 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Here, `1 2 3` are the default "base" paramters I *always* want to pass to the ENTRYPOINT, `7` is the default "additional" parameters, and `4 5 6` provided to override the default parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few brief details that lie behind DazWilkin's answer:

If you `docker inspect` the `prom/prometheus` image, you'll find the
following:

```
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/prometheus"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
                "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus",
                "--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries",
                "--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles"
            ],
```

When you run:

```
docker run ... prom/prometheus --enable-feature=promql-at-modifier
```

You are replacing the existing `Cmd` setting, so the command actually
executed is `/bin/prometheus --enable-feature=promql-at-modifier`. To
provide the same behavior as  you get by  default, you would actually
want to run:

```
docker run ... prom/prometheus \
  --enable-feature=promql-at-modifier \
  --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
  --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus \
  --web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries \
  --web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles
```